# Dropdown list Checklist Combination Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, drop-down-menu, checklistbox

I want to create a dropdown list, which has the checklist functionality. I.e., I have a bunch of email senders' names in respective checkboxes, each checkbox selected when clicking a download button, will be included in a data extraction function.

I have tried the package, ChecklistCombobox, which I can't manage to install, import and use:
https://pypi.org/project/ChecklistCombobox/

Comment: ttkbootstrap have some combobox features, you can look [here](https://ttkbootstrap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/styleguide/combobox/)